# How can I import Vue component into application created in php file?

Tags: php, vue.js, yii2

I'm included into some old project made in Yii2, which already consists hundreds of models and  views.
I'm thinking about bringing some new breeze to it by adding Vue3 on top of existing platform.

I see 2 possibilities:
1st step is adding Vue to php view files in such way, that each view is its own application.
2nd step is creating in the future new Yii modules with use of Inertia.

For now i want to convience my team that Vue is great and easy to use (other people just know basics of JS and jquery). Show them basics: v-if, v-for, v-model etc.

Im able to run Vue by adding it to existing php view like that:

```php
<?php
use yii\web\View;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\select2\Select2;


<div class="cechy-form" id="app">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName()]); ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'nazwa')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'v-model' => 'model.nazwa']) ?>

            <?=
                $form->field($model, 'typ_cechy')->widget(Select2::class, [
                    'data' => \Yii::$app->params['inwentarz_cechy'],
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Wybierz...', 'v-model' => 'model.typ_cechy'],
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
                    'pluginEvents' => [
                        "change" => "function() { toggleList(); toggleInfo(); }",
                    ]
                ]);
            ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'lista')->textArea(['style' => 'height: auto !important', 'v-model' => 'model.lista'])->label('elementy listy (wprowadzaj w oddzielnych wierszach)') ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'info')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'v-model' => 'model.info']) ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('inwentarz', 'Zapisz'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'display' => 'hidden']) ?>
            </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

<script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js';

    createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                model: {
                    type: Object,
                    value: null,
                },
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.model = <?= json_encode($model->attributes) ?>;
        }
    }).mount('#app');
</script>
```

What i've done here was creating app and mounting it into div cointaining Yii2 ActiveForm, adding v-model to inputs and passing values with php in created() lifecycle method. It works.

What im unnable to do is importing existing components. First thing needed above is to replace Kartik Select2 with vue3-select2-component.

I was trying to create own super simple component for test:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello Vue3
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'DoubleWrapper'
}
</script>
```

Used webpack to compile it into app.js file (below is webpack.config.js)

```js
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './app/App.vue',
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../web/apps/inwentarz'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.vue$/, use: 'vue-loader' }],
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Than try to import webpacked file:

```js
/* 
(...)
<div id="app">
(...)
</div>
*/
<script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js';
    import DoubleWrapper from '/apps/inwentarz/app.js';

    createApp({
        components: {
            DoubleWrapper,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                model: {
                    type: Object,
                    value: null,
                },
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.model = <?= json_encode($model->attributes) ?>;
        }
    }).mount('#app');
</script>
```

Now i get error in console: "The requested module '/apps/inwentarz/app.js' does not provide an export named 'default'".

Comment: Also tried to import packed script in header. Error is than "Uncaught ReferenceError: DoubleWrapper is not defined".

Comment: Have you checked that your webpack built JavaScript is also included before trying to use it? 

In general I would advise you to not inline the JavaScript in the template but deliver it separately, helps with auto completion and also brings a better separation. I don’t know how much interactivity you need but from what you write about the existing team maybe it would be worth to take a look at htmx as it allows to add some interactivity easily to existing classic web pages.

Comment: Not inlining your js code should also help with your error because the error appears because the template file is not processed via webpack and outside of webpack there is no concept of imports in JavaScript. So in your case you should just include your bundled entry point script app.js as it should do all the bootstrapping and binding that is currently done in your inline script.